Starting process in docker separate from entrypoint
I am using a docker image whose base image is bookworm-slim.  I think the image doesn't have a way to queue up startup services (perhaps I have to install that as well?), but I want to run CRON alongside whatever application I plan to execute in ENTRYPOINT.
Is there a cleaner way to run both cron and the entrypoint application without using a shell script?
What's the leanest way to do that?

Run the cron daemon in a separate container.  You can override the image's command when you launch the container so that the single process in the second container is something else.

How to run a cron job inside a docker container? seems to cover this space, though the examples there tend to either have an image that only runs cron, or use a shell script that doesn't monitor one process or the other.


Is there a cleaner way to run both cron and the entrypoint application without using a shell script?

If you want a generic solution, you'll need a shell script as your ENTRYPOINT that runs cron in the background and then runs your primary command. Something like:
#!/bin/sh

cron
exec "$@"

This assumes you're using cron from the Debian cron package, which automatically puts itself in the background. This may not be the best choice for a containerized cron daemon because it logs to syslog instead of stdout (and you don't have a syslog service running inside the container). I often use crond from busybox, which has options for logging to a file instead of syslog (and "file" can include things like /dev/stdout), but the Debian busybox package doesn't include crond.
Note that in many situations it makes more sense to run cron in a separate container, rather than setting up a container with multiple primary processes. Whether or not this makes sense really depends on your particular use case.

If you really don't want a shell script as your ENTRYPOINT, you could investigate some sort of process supervisor that permits drop-in configuration; I've seen people use tools like supervisord and runit for this purpose. You would have a default configuration that runs cron, and then your final image would install an appropriate configuration file that would launch your primary application.
Here is an example that sets up a base image that uses runit as a service manager. The base image starts both cron and a syslog service that logs to stdout. A second image builds on top of the base by adding the Apache web server.
